# How can you add custom artifacts in a SBT command

Tags: scala, sbt

Can anyone show me how to add multiple `Artifacts` within a SBT `Command`? I want to do the following. Given the following tree:

```
  - target
     |- scala-2.10
         |- classes
             |- my
                 |- package
                     |- foo
                      - bar
                      - john
                      - doe
```

I want to create a command that publishes a individual `Artifact` (jar) for each folder under `my/package`. There should not be any default `Artifact`. Projects that depend on this library should use classifiers, i.e.

```
libraryDependencies += "whatever" % "whatever" % "1.0" Artifacts(Artifact("foo", "john") )
```

Here is what I have so far.

```
def myCommand = Command.single("myCommand") {
    case (currentState, arg) =>
      val extracted = Project.extract(currentState)

      val compileDirectory = extracted.get[File](classDirectory in Compile)
      val packageDir = new sbt.File(compileDirectory, s"my${File.separator}package")
      val artifactDefinitions = IO.listFiles(packageDir).toList.map {
        serviceDir =>
          val serviceName = serviceDir.name.split(File.separatorChar).reverse.head
          println(s"Adding artifact for $serviceName")

          val serviceTask = taskKey[File](s"Adds a $serviceName artifact")
          serviceTask := {
            serviceDir
          }
          val definition = addArtifact(Artifact("service", serviceName), serviceTask)
          extracted.append(definition.settings, currentState) <-- fails on this line
          definition
      }

      currentState
  }
```

Error I am getting:

```
Reference to undefined setting: 

  *:serviceTask from *:packagedArtifacts ((sbt.BuildExtra) Defaults.scala:1767)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  def myCommand = Command.single("myCommand") {
    case (currentState, arg) =>
      val extracted = Project.extract(currentState)

      val targetDirectory = extracted.get[File](target in Compile)
      val compileDirectory = extracted.get[File](classDirectory in Compile)
      val packageDir = new sbt.File(compileDirectory, s"my${java.io.File.separator}package")
      val additionalArtifacts =  IO.listFiles(packageDir).toList.map {  serviceDir =>
        val serviceName = serviceDir.name.split(java.io.File.separatorChar).reverse.head
        println(s"Adding artifact for $serviceName")

        val files = Path.allSubpaths(serviceDir)
        val outputZip = new sbt.File(targetDirectory, s"$serviceName.jar")
        sbt.IO.zip(files, outputZip)

        (Artifact(serviceName, serviceName), outputZip)
      }.toMap

      val settings = Seq[Setting[_]](
        packagedArtifacts ++= additionalArtifacts,
        artifacts ++= additionalArtifacts.keys.toSeq
      )

      extracted.append(settings, s)
  }
```

Comment: thanks that fixes the error. When I run this however, I never see those artifacts - neither in `target` nor in `~/.ivy/local` after running `publish-local`. Am I missing anything? What I would like to have is individual jars containing the classes in `foo`, `bar`, `john` and `doe`.

Comment: Yes you're missing that you're defining an artifact with a directory, not a packaged file. I wouldn't recommend going down this route at all, it reminds me of ant and why maven's conventions (which sbt adopted) worked so well: keep a simple 1-to-1 relationship between source and artifact. So I would recommend you organise your build to be multiple projects and use what's out the box instead of going down this route.

Comment: Yes you are right in a way. This project just contains a lot of .thrift files, which will generate source code. I want to package the classes generated for each .thrift file into a separate artifact which I can then use in another project using the classifier syntax. If I create a multi-project build and each thrift files lives in it's own project, I would not be able to use classifiers like `libraryDependencies += "whatever" % "whatever" % "1.0" Artifacts(Artifact("foo", "john") )` correct?

Comment: Correct, they'd have to be `"whatever" % "whatever-foo" % "1.0"` and  `"whatever" % "whatever-john" % "1.0"`. But you'll be following the convention and everything will work smoothly out the box.

Comment: Got it working now, cheers. Modifying `packagedArtifacts` and `packaged` in each `foldLeft` iteration didn't work however. Only the Artifact of the last iteration got added. I changed your answer now, so that instead of using `foldLeft` I do a `map` and add all Artifacts in one go.